# What is the meaning of "May I also take this opportunity of..."?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of the following sentence in simple terms?

> May I also take this opportunity of welcoming you on board at our company.

I searched the web but couldn't find something similar.

Comment: It's just a super-polite way of saying "Welcome to our company". The speaker asks permission to do so (May I?) and is 'taking the opportunity' (saying it at a convenient moment).

Comment: I agree with @KateBunting, but I think I'd say "May I take this opportunity *to welcome you*" though. Otherwise you could say "May I also take this opportunity of welcoming you on board at our company to present you with this commemorative tie pin."